# three.js JSONLoader Material Not Showing

Tags: json, three.js

I am trying to import an object from Maya and here is the json file

```
{

    "metadata" :
    {
        "formatVersion" : 3.1,
        "sourceFile"    : "myobj.obj",
        "generatedBy"   : "OBJConverter",
        "vertices"      : 22470,
        "faces"         : 42837,
        "normals"       : 128511,
        "colors"        : 0,
        "uvs"           : 52126,
        "materials"     : 1
    },

    "scale" : 1.000000,

    "materials": [  {
        "DbgColor" : 15658734,
        "DbgIndex" : 0,
        "DbgName" : "lambert2SG",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        "illumination" : 4,
        "mapDiffuse" : "mytexture.tga",
        "opticalDensity" : 1.0
    }],
    "vertices": [...] //Omitted because there are too many
    "morphTargets": [],
    "morphColors": [],
    "normals": [...],
    "colors": [],
    "uvs": [...],
    "faces": [...]
}
```

and here is how I load the JSON file:

Here is how I initialize the scene and load the json file. I have a large far point because objects are huge:

```
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100000);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        var mesh;
        var render = function () {
            stats.update();
            controls.update();
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        jsonLoader.load("Mesh/myobj.js", function(geometry, materials){
            console.log(materials); // This prints an array, whose first element is a MeshLambertMaterial.
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( materials )); 
            // If I remove the second parameter, 
            //the object renders correctly without texture. 
            //Otherwise the screen shows nothing.
            console.log(geometry);
            scene.add(mesh);
        });
        render();
        camera.position.y = 10000;
```

Sorry if I've done something stupid. I am new to three.js.
The screen displays nothing if I apply texture to the object. I've tried everything I can find. Please help!

Comment: Try `new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials )`.

Comment: @WestLangley That didn't work. Sorry :(

Comment: three.js does not support .tga files. convert the file to .png.

Comment: @WestLangley I just tried that. Nope. But I discovered that none of the objects would show up if they have a material attached, not even a basic blue cube. Probably I am missing something. I am updating the post with more code.

Comment: I think I have found the issue (after 6 hours of trial and error). 
For some reason I can't directly apply materials from JSONLoader. I have to use ImageUtils to manually load texture from file. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your camera to scene properly? `scene.add(camera);`

Comment: I did.:( I found out if I load texture separately it works. So I am guessing I can't use texture from JSONLoader.

Comment: Try this link. Hope it would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872502/jsonloader-with-texture