# threejs cannot parse material in json object

Tags: json, parsing, three.js

Dear all I am using angular 2.4.10 and three js 0.85.0. After downloading a JSON file from the server, I have at my disposal the following JSON object:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7IcIHZN137RdmVRTXpLZmlPaDg/view?usp=sharing

I am trying to load the object without using the loader URL using the following code suggested in another StackOverflow post:

```
loadModel(aJSONObject) {
    console.log(aJSONObject);

    let loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

    let model = loader.parse( aJSONObject );

    console.log(model);

    .....
}
```

and it's working but it is not getting the materials. How can I get the material from the JSON file?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872502/jsonloader-with-texture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to load your model and the unique material got imported correctly.

However, there is no texture nor color defined for this material in the JSON model. So the object will look white, the default color used for three.js materials.

[Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/x903bxob/)

To see your model in three.js make sure to scale it appropriately based on you camera position (I had to scale it down).
Moreover, as the model is using a `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial`, don't forget to add some lights.

---

By the way, there are some `X`, `Y` and `Z` individual attributes defined in your model that increase its size uselessly (three.js won't use them).

Comment: Thank you neeh, you are a star. Just one more clarification if you know the answer. If I just apply the following code: 
`var objLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
 var object = objLoader.parse(json);` without using the THREE.FileLoader (as my service get the JSON object for me) I still obtain a Object3D that I can use for rendering but it is missing few fields compared to the object returned by the FileLoader. For example, your code returns a bbox (bounding box that is not present in the object returned without using the file load. Do you know why?

Comment: Your `THREE.Mesh` is contained inside a `THREE.Object3D`. What you're looking for is `object.children[0]`.
If you're looking for the `boundingBox`, you should find it in the geometry of your mesh : `object.children[0].geometry.boundingBox`.
`THREE.FileLoader` won't change anything. Check the data returned by your service. If you really don't have a `boundingBox`, compute it with `object.children[0].geometry.computeBoundingBox()`.

Comment: Thank you, very much Neeh. You saved me a lot of headaches.